# Cannot install separate user account profiles on Fusion tablet running Android 4.4.2

Tags: multi-user

We have a Samsung Chromebook and a Nexus 7 in the house that both allow us to set-up distinct different user accounts on them which we find most useful.

We have just acquired a new non-brandname tablet (Fusion) running 4.4.2 KitKat, and it will not allow us to set-up separate accounts as we have been able to on other Android devices.

I assume that must be something to do with the way that the manufacturer has set up Adnroid 4.4.2 on their device as opposed to a a problem with the OS.

Can anybody recommend a workaround that a non=technical novice could manage without too much pain being involved?

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the exact same issue when trying to set up users on a no brand tablet. My tablet was rooted out of the box, so I installed Xposed and then the module [Multiple Users for Phone](http://repo.xposed.info/module/droidmate.multiuser.xposed). Even though the title says it's for phones, it works flawlessly on my tablet. It adds the option `Users` to your settings page.

Info about Xposed from the installer page:

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the
>   system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it
>   means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs
>   without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too
>   much). It's also easy to undo. As all changes are done in the memory,
>   you just need to deactivate the module and reboot to get your original
>   system back. There are many other advantages, but here is just one
>   more: Multiple modules can do changes to the same part of the system
>   or app. With modified APKs, you to decide for one. No way to combine
>   them, unless the author builds multiple APKs with different
>   combinations.

If you want clearer instructions on how to install, comment and I'll edit the question. I can't link to all the links because I don't have 10 reputation (yet).

Comment: Xposed installer: http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer